# Find the value of $\iint_R(f(x,y) + 2) \,dx\,dy$ over area $[0,2] \times [0,2]$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

So I'm taking a calculus course and I admit I don't quite understand this topic in my course.

Given that the integral of the function $f(x,y)$ over the area $[0,2] \times [0,2]$ equals $4$ , how can we compute the value of the integral
$$\iint_R(f(x,y) + 2) \,dx\,dy\,\,?$$

So
$$\iint_R(f(x,y) + 2) \,dx\,dy = \iint_R f(x,y) \,dx\,dy + 2\iint_R \,dx\,dy$$

Then $4  + 2\iint_R \,dx\,dy$? But I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

I'm guessing the bound $R$ is equivalent to writing $\int_0^2\int_0^2(f(x,y) + 2) \,dx\,dy$?
I would really appreciate some help as I'm super confused (as mentioned, new topic for me). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f=4$ over $[0,2] \times [0,2]$, then
$$\int_0^2\int_0^2(f(x,y) + 2) dxdy= \int_0^2\int_0^2f(x,y) dxdy+8=4\cdot 4+8=24$$

**Addition.**

Of course, if $\int_0^2\int_0^2f(x,y) dxdy = 4$, then answer will be $12$:
$$\int\limits_0^2\int_\limits0^2(f(x,y) + 2) dxdy= \int_\limits0^2\int_\limits0^2f(x,y) dxdy+2\int_\limits0^2\int_\limits0^2dxdy =\\
= 4+2\cdot \int\limits_{0}^{2}dx \cdot \int\limits_{0}^{2}dy =12$$

Comment: On region $[0,2] \times [0,2]$ there is no other way. May be your region $R$ is not $[0,2] \times [0,2]$?

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, my bad! So the  integral* of the function is 4. Made an edit.

Comment: It's more appropriate to write additions to post rather, then correct it in place. Look, please, how I made it.

Comment: I see, will note for next time thx! In regards to your answer, would you mind explaining it though? I don't quite understand it.

Comment: Write in addition in more detail - in which part you have doubt?

Comment: The $2 * 4$ part I don't care understand, how did you derive these? (the 2 is obvious  but how did you get 4?)

Comment: As integrand is constant $1$, then you can separate variables.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand